# Self-hosted WebAPI and multiple post and get methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have got implemented console self-hosted WebAPI app.

My controller works fine for single get and post methods.

**I cannot get how to implementg multiple get and posts methods in ApiController**

**Startup.cs**

```
 class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Initialize WebAPI
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "apiRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            // Initialize SignalR
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR(); 
        } 
    }
```

**ApiController that works fine**

```
public class MessageController : ApiControllerWithHub<SignalMessageHub>
{
   public IEnumerable<MyItem> GetMessages()
   {
      //Code
   }

   public HttpResponseMessage PostNewMessage(User user)
   {
      // code  
   }
}
```

**ApiController that does not work**

```
public class MessageController : ApiControllerWithHub<SignalMessageHub>
{
   public IEnumerable<MyItem> GetMessages()
   {
      //Code
   }

   // Cannot route to those methods 
   [HttpPost()]
   [Route("api/Message/NewMessage")]
   public HttpResponseMessage PostNewMessage(User user)
   {
      // code  
   }

   [HttpPost()]
   [Route("api/Message/NewMessage2")]
   public HttpResponseMessage PostNewMessage2(User user)
   {
      // code  
   }

}
```

Comment: Try changing your routing from this `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",` to `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",` and remove `api/Message` from the Actions `Route` then you should be able to get them on `"api/Message/NewMessage"`

Comment: @Dimi Sorry, posted before the edit! Samvel's answer looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with your Routing.
Here

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
```

You have not added "{action}" so you can't get Actions until you change this to this:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Also you have added "api/Message" to the Action's routing in the controller which will make your routing to something like:

```
api/{controller}/{action}/api/Message/NewMessage
```

So you need to remove it also.